# how to link ffmpeg to php.ini

Tags: ffmpeg, php

hi i am using mac osx with mamp and i was wondering how i can link ffmpeg to php.ini so that i can use it with php exec() ?

the directory that ffmpeg got installed in is /users/sarmenhb/ffmpeg although i wish it didnt get installed here and got installed somewhere more appropriate, i sadly have no clue how to change the system to know where the new location is.

i read a few articles telling me to put something like extensions = /users/sarmenhb/ffmpeg/ffmpeg.so but looking in the directory i dont see a so file. i do see ffmpeg as a console app is that an so file itself?

thanks

ps: i did a test of ffmpeg in console from a flv file to a mp4 file and the audio didnt work on the new file. do i have to install something?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the full path when executing ffmpeg:

```
exec("/users/sarmenhb/ffmpeg");
```